# Parenthesis and number? What is it after a command?

Tags: command-line

I recently came across the useradd command and looked at the manual page. It alluded to useradd(8). What is the significance of the number and how is the command applied?

Comment: [Answered here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/what-do-the-numbers-in-a-man-page-mean) (also [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/647051/what-do-numbers-between-parentheses-in-bash-man-pages-mean-bash1-ssh-config) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173618/what-does-the-number-in-brackets-after-a-command-in-the-manpages-mean/173621#173621)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man man`:

```
The table below shows the section numbers of the manual followed by the types of pages they contain.

1   Executable programs or shell commands
2   System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
3   Library calls (functions within program libraries)
4   Special files (usually found in /dev)
5   File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
6   Games
7   Miscellaneous (including macro packages and conventions), e.g. man(7), groff(7)
8   System administration commands (usually only for root)
9   Kernel routines [Non standard]
```

The number refers to a section number of the manual. In your example, if you want to find the man page for `useradd` in section 8 of the manual, you run:

```
man 8 useradd
```

Answer (score 3):

It is a reference to another manual page. Some of the commands have same name as system functions ( used in programming language ) .  You can view the other page via `man -e 8 useradd`

Answer (score 0):

The 8 specifies that this is a administration and privileged command. For a complete list of possibilities please view http://linux.die.net/man/.

useradd, as the name implies, is used to add users to a system. The basic syntax is:

```
useradd [options] USERNAME
```

In order to add a user called ikazmi, you would use the following command:

```
$- useradd ikazmi
```

If you want the user ikazmi to be able to login, you'll have to create a password for them:

```
$- passwd ikazmi
```

In order to add the user ikazmi to any groups, you can use useradd with 'G' as an option:

```
$- useradd -G sudo,www-data,cdrom ikazmi
```

Hope this helps.